# Add php page in wordpress outside the theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a php page (`test.php`) in my root directory (WWW) where wordpress is installed. I don't want to use the custom template method (add this page in my wordpress theme directory)
I have added in this php file this:

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
?>
<h1>Test</h1>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

When I do: `www.example.com/test.php` this page is correctly loading but the title of this page display "`error 404`"

I **don't** understand how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: This is bad practice, even for Wordpress. Make a plugin/childtheme etc

Answer (score 3):

you need to include wp-load.php to use header, in your case replace `require('wp-blog-header.php');` with

```
<?php require_once('wp-load.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks its done but its the same, i get an error 404 in my page title and the class of <body> display : <body class="error404 ...">

Comment: You need to replace `require('wp-blog-header.php');` with `require_once('wp-load.php');` hope it will help you

Comment: If this resolve your problem, than mark it as right so that other user can also get the help from your question

Answer (score 1):

I have placed this code in my root directory in test.php file. This code is working fine if you replace require('wp-blog-header.php'); with require_once('wp-load.php');

Comment: Perfect ! Its works when i replace wp-blog-header by wp-load. Thank you !